# Can I ask that someone reviews my edits

Tags: feature-request, support, review, edits

I have enough reputation that my edits are immediately applied. Sometimes I still feel that they should be peer reviewed, just because I'm not completely sure that my edit was correct. On these situations just leaving a comment isn't usually an appropriate solution, because edits are so major that just leaving comment won't get the problem solved.

**Can I somehow ask my edits to get peer reviewed?**

If not, could this feature be added?

Note: While that situation is fairly common in codegolf.SE, I'm not really sure if that happens on other sites.

Comment: You'd better ask in a chat room you are active in if people agree with your suggested edit.

Comment: Another "way around", is creating a new account, and suggest your edits from that account. As long as you don't double-vote, double-flag etc, it should be OK.